# JavaFX InputMap/ActionMap equivalent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx, hotkeys

I'm finally switching over fully to JavaFX.

I'm very keen on keystroke functionality.

Is there an equivalent hotkey architecture to the (very good) one you find in Swing? How does it work in the case of a JavaFX text control object?  I thought all might become clear if I took a look at `javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl`. Also tried googling of course.

But I'm none the wiser.  Presumably there must be a source of the minimal keystroke bindings you need when editing text?  Is it similarly hierarchical?

With Swing every `JComponent` can use 1 `ActionMap` and 3 `InputMaps` (and all of these can have "ancestor" maps).  The 3 `InputMap` "types" are determined by the `JComponent` constants `WHEN_FOCUSED`, `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` and `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` which are pretty self-explanatory names.  I seriously wonder how many Swing users are familiar with all this stuff but personally, being a keyboard fanatic, I use this functionality extensively.

Being able to attach a key binding to a given `javafx.scene.Node` using `setOnKeyPressed` is presumably equivalent to using the `WHEN_FOCUSED` Swing functionality... but what about the other two categories, I wonder? Are they simply absent in the current implementation of JavaFX?

Ultimately, with Swing, behind the scenes there is obviously a very sophisticated mechanism involving keystrokes being "passed up" the hierarchical structure of `JComponent` objects until they are "caught" by an `InputMap` (or not)... presumably there must be something a bit like this in JavaFX.  It'd be nice to have chapter and verse...

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/tutorial-how-to-setup-key-combinations-in-javafx/)?

Comment: @ToddSewell thanks... begins to answer it, yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaFX you can register a callback for `KeyPressed` events.

For example:

```
myTextField.setOnKeyPressed(event->{
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

If you wanted to register a global Key combination (say, the typical Ctrl-S for saving) you could instead use:

```
myScene.getAccellerators().put(
    new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN),
            () -> { /** save my work **/ }
    )
```

List of available KeyCodeCombinations: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCodeCombination.html

**EDIT(1): how event propagation works**

From http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm

The event delivery process contains the following steps:

- Target selection
- Route construction
- Event capturing
- Event bubbling

Comment: Thanks... please see my update.  Actually I failed to spot that method because like an idiot I was mistaking (in the Javadoc) the huge list of inherited *properties* for TextField for *methods*!

Comment: No worries. I have updated my answer to provide info on event propagation.

If overall you think that this answer has helped you or, more importantly, could help someone else in the future visiting this post, consider marking it as Accepted. cheers.

Comment: Useful link, going to see what light it sheds.  I shall of course accept an answer in due course... but it's not too good to do it too early because an "answered" question discourages future potential answers.  When I answer a q on SO I don't have any expectation about upvotes, downvotes or indeed accepts.

Comment: Apologies Mike, I didn't mean to rush you or imply you had to accept my answer if you didn't want to. It came out wrong I guess. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Aha.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156039/how-to-override-installed-mappings-of-behavior/35178499), from a year ago, already relating to Java 9, reveals what looks like future existence in JavaFX of `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap`... obviously at the moment 
package `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap` does not exist (in Java 8) (unless I'm very much mistaken).

The person who posed that question, Kleopatra, is something of an expert in Java Swing, and presumably now in JavaFX.  We see some early releases of Java 9 happening around now, March 2017, precisely... but having tried googling for the API Javadoc for JavaFX 9, I can't as yet see any sign of `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap`.