# Access the built-in shortcuts of PyQt5 components?

Tags: python, pyqt5, shortcut, hotkeys

I'm very keen on being able to use the keyboard to do everything with a GUI and am currently exploring `QTreeView` and `QTableView` among other things.

I'm adding a lot of my own hotkeys (shortcuts) and am devising a method to automate a user list or guide to these available hotkeys.

But something like `QTreeView` also comes with its own built-in hotkeys, e.g. arrow keys for navigation, F2 to start editing, Ctrl-A for "select all", etc.. I want to get a comprehensive list of these and include them in the automatically generated user guide.

I've got to [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/accelerators.html), for example, but I haven't really got a clue how to dig down into PyQt5 components to unearth this kind of information programmatically.

There's some interesting functionality, probably unknown to many users, with `QTreeView`: e.g. if, in column 0, you have a tree structure you can skip from label (text) to label by pressing the first letter of each one's label. But if you enter 2 (or more) keys quickly enough this also works: entering "ra" will skip over "Roma" and "Rimini" to "Ravenna" even if "Roma" and "Rimini" come first. It turns out that this is implemented by [QTreeView.keyboardSearch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#keyboardSearch) ... but what I want to know is whether it's possible to find details of the "mapping" functionality for this and other keyboard enablements, often implemented by `keyPressEvent`, programmatically. Having looked a little at the PyQt5 files it seems that a lot of PyQt5 functionality may ultimately be contained in .dll files (this is a W10 machine), so I'm not particularly optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

Each widget has a certain behavior depending on the hotkeys pressed, so there is no documentation that indicates all the cases, so you will have to review the documentation of each class and the parent class. So for example to understand the behavior of QTableView you should also review the documentation of QAbstractItemView, QAbstractScrollArea and QFrame (the same is for QTreeView), considering the above we can collect information:

> [`void QAbstractScrollArea::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#keyPressEvent)
> This function is called with key event e when key presses occur. It
> handles PageUp, PageDown, Up, Down, Left, and Right, and ignores all
> other key presses.

[`QAbstractItemView:`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#details)

[image]

> [`void QAbstractItemView::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#keyPressEvent).
>
> This function is called with the given event when a key event is sent
> to the widget. The default implementation handles basic cursor
> movement, e.g. Up, Down, Left, Right, Home, PageUp, and PageDown; the
> activated() signal is emitted if the current index is valid and the
> activation key is pressed (e.g. Enter or Return, depending on the
> platform). **This function is where editing is initiated by key press,
> e.g. if F2 is pressed.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

QTableView and QTreeView when inheriting from QAbstractItemView have the same hotkeys.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm looking for is not documentation, but a way of accessing the hotkey info programmatically. In Java Swing this did prove possible, although not easy, by exploring things like `InputMap`s and `ActionMap`s (associated with Swing component classes). In JavaFX I was unable to access this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713630/javafx-inputmap-actionmap-equivalent. I've already found `keyPressEvent` ... I'll see whether there's a way of spying on default implementations...